# Camera preview on SurfaceView is stretched despite setting sizes

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to make the camera preview correctly show up on a `SurfaceView`. However, despite trying to `getSupportedPictureSizes()` and setting both `pictureSize` and `previewSize` to one of the values from the list, the preview is still very, very stretched.

I decided I wanted the size to be 1280 by 720 pixels, and I've set this value everywhere (and again, it's on the `getSupportedPictureSizes()`, as well as `getSupportedPreviewSizes()`)

I have browsed all of the Stackoverflow posts on the issue, and I can't seem to get it solved. Any help is appreciated.

**surfaceCreated() for my SurfaceHolder:**

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

    parameters.setPictureSize(1280, 720);
    parameters.setPreviewSize(1280, 720);

    Log.d("SurfaceView", surfaceView.getWidth() + ", " + surfaceView.getHeight());

    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

    previewCamera();
}
```

**SurfaceView design XML:**

```
<SurfaceView
    android:layout_width="1280px"
    android:layout_height="720px"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/surfaceViewCamera"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

**Entire activity class:**

```
package org.ownzone.security_droid;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AuthenticatedActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private ServerConnection sc = ServerConnection.getServerConnectionInstance();
    private boolean active;

    private Camera camera;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private boolean isPreviewRunning;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_authenticated);

        active = false;
        isPreviewRunning = false;

        TextView headline = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewHeadLine);
        headline.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("cardholder") + " authenticated");

        Switch activeSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchActive);
        activeSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                active = isChecked;
            }
        });

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewCamera);

        camera = Camera.open();

        for (Camera.Size size : camera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes())
        {
            Log.d("Size", size.width + ", " + size.height);
        }

        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(surfaceHolderCallback);
        //camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceView.getHolder());
        //camera.startPreview();

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }

    private void takePhoto()
    {
        camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawPictureCallback, jpegPictureCallback);
    }

    SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceHolderCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback()
    {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

            parameters.setPictureSize(1280, 720);
            parameters.setPreviewSize(1280, 720);

            Log.d("SurfaceView", surfaceView.getWidth() + ", " + surfaceView.getHeight());

            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

            previewCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
        {

        }
    };

    public void previewCamera()
    {
        try
        {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
            isPreviewRunning = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("AuthenticatedActivity", "Cannot start preview", e);
        }
    }


    Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback()
    {
        public void onShutter()
        {

        }
    };

    Camera.PictureCallback rawPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback()
    {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
        {

        }
    };

    Camera.PictureCallback jpegPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback()
    {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
        {
            Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            Bitmap correctBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapPicture, 0, 0, bitmapPicture.getWidth(), bitmapPicture.getHeight(), null, true);

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Which device is this? Are you sire it does support 1280x720 preview? And what is stretched? The captured still JPEG picture, or live preview on screen, or the bitmap rendered on an ImageView? It would be easier if you could post an update with sample JPEG and screenshots that demonstrate the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Without a screenshot, this is a bit of a guess, but I'd suspect your call to setDisplayOrientation.

A hardcoded value there may work for a single device or a set of devices, but in general, you need to take into account several factors - see the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)

And in general, on most devices (but not all!), if you have a landscape app on a phone, you'll end up with calling setDisplayOrientation(0), not 90.

Is your app landscape- or portrait-oriented (or flexible?)? And a screenshot would be very helpful in ruling out various issues.